# What is the intracellular chloride concentration in rat T-cells or thymocytes

Tags: cell-biology

I'm modeling acid-base in T-cells as based on Grinstein J Gen Physiol 1984; 83: 341-369. I have an estimate of strong ion difference (SID), and Grinstein gives Na and K, but for SID to be true at 33 mM with K 147 mM and Na perhaps 20 mM Cl should be  (K + Na) - SID = 134 mM which is hard to believe but I could find no data on the subject.

Comment: Where is your estimate of SID from?

Answer (score 1):

Felber and Brand 1982 estimate the intracellular T-cell chloride concentration to be about 30 mmol, which seems to me to be on the high end for intracellular chloride in mammalian cells (though my experience is mostly with neurons, I'm not as confident of intracellular chloride concentrations in other cell types; for a neuron I'd expect <10mmol). Still, that leaves a big anion gap for your SID estimate.

I think it is more likely that your SID estimate is simply wrong. The number you report sounds like an extracellular SID; Kowalchuk et al 1988 suggest intracellular SID is about 4X extracellular for muscle, which sounds about right for your situation as well.

Most of the intracellular anion contribution is provided by negatively charged proteins, amino acids, lactate, etc, rather than strong ions like chloride. Many of these are nearly completely deprotonated at physiological pH, though (for a typical amino acid the first pKa is ~2).

---

Felber, S. M., & Brand, M. D. (1982). Factors determining the plasma-membrane potential of lymphocytes. Biochemical Journal, 204(2), 577-585.

Kowalchuk, J. M., Heigenhauser, G. J., Lindinger, M. I., Sutton, J. R., & Jones, N. L. (1988). Factors influencing hydrogen ion concentration in muscle after intense exercise. Journal of Applied Physiology, 65(5), 2080-2089.

Comment: Thanks a lot - my estimate of SID was based on a buffer capacity of 25 mmol/l/pH as reported by Grinstein at pH 7 - for lack of other knowledge assuming a KA of 2e-7 like histidine gives from Van Slyke 1922 JBC equation 17 an estimate of ATOT , and from that using charge balance a value for SID.. But I can see you have to model the many negative charges on proteins in a different way. Thanks a lot for this help

Comment: @user37217 If this answer [addressed your problem](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.